# Bundle a Blazor Component's JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor, components, .net-8.0

Blazor components support CSS bundling and cohesiveness: `Foo.razor` would have `Foo.razor.css`, which will: a) enjoy [CSS isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation); b) bundle into `{ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css`.

What I'm after is a similar mechanism for component-scoped JavaScript.

I **don't** want to put generic functions in the global scope (`window`) and call them via `jsComponentInitializers` as demonstrated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/js-spa-frameworks), mainly because it breaks the idea of components as cohesive units; and also since if I put my JavaScript code within the `.razor` file, I end up having the same code repeated and scattered throughout the page, as I use multiple instances of that component.

The rendering mode is Static server-side rendering (SSR).

**Is there a way to use JavaScript in a custom Blazor component such that it bundles into something similar to `{ASSEMBLY NAME}.scripts.js`, or any other form, and exists only once?** (note that I still want to be able to distinguish between component instances in a similar way to the way CSS is component-isolated)

Comment: I mean you could have a sperate TS project that you webpack into a bundle or sets of bundles and then just include all *.ts files in in your blazor index page using something like 

<link rel="stylesheet" asp-href-include="~/dist/styles.bundle.*.css" />
<script type="module" asp-src-include="~/dist/site.entry.*.js"></script>

Comment: Thank you @JacquesRamsden. It helps indeed, in that the JS won't be scattered throughout the page and won't be duplicated. But is there a way to know which specific component called my function? (in case I have several of the same component on the same page).

Comment: Do you mean which controller called the js layer or which is later component called another function?

Comment: Maybe if you could provide an example of what you mean by which component called my function.

Comment: @JacquesRamsden let's say I have a TableComponent that has all sorts of client-side behavior, for instance: sorting when clicking a header. And I have several of these TableComponent instances on my page. When I click an header, which invokes some custom JS click event, I want the click event to know which actual TableComponent instance it touches.

Comment: Surly event.target should solve this for you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Comment: Yeah, I can, I just hoped there'd be a less hack-y way to do it - something more structured in Blazor component model, similar to how each component instance gets a unique ID in CSS

Comment: I mean you could go down that road but I feel like that will just lead to code duplication all over the place. Unless what you are wanting to do is something like... make button component. Re-use button component with same logic but be able to for example update user x where each button is assigned to a specific user.  In that case. You may want to add data properties that you bind to the button through attributes. This can then be used to identify which object the trigger is related to. Hop that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blazor doesn't support JavaScript isolation in the same way it does for CSS. However, you can use a JavaScript bundler to compile multiple files into a single file. To do this, download the [Bundler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Failwyn.BundlerMinifier64) extension in Visual Studio 2022. Then, create a configuration file in your root directory with the following content:

```
{
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/bundle.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/ts/file1.js",
      "wwwroot/js/ts/file2.js",
      "wwwroot/js/ts/file3.js",
      "wwwroot/js/ts/file4.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "outputMode": "singleLine",
      "commentMode": "important",
      "adjustRelativePaths": true,
      "renameLocals": true,
      "gzip": true
    },
    "sourceMap": true
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Suryateja. It helps indeed, in that the JS won't be scattered throughout the page and won't be duplicated. But is there a way to know which specific component called my function? (in case I have several of the same component on the same page).